# MYSQL: Merge two tables into one, with union

Tags: mysql, union

I have to make a table out of two other tables (and use union). The query that works is:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel1
UNION
SELECT * FROM tabel2
```

Now what i have to do is put this result(data) into table3 (a table i already have, with the same columns as in table1 and table2).

Who can help me?

Comment: did you try an `INSERT`?

Answer (score 25):

```
INSERT INTO table3 
SELECT * FROM tabel1
UNION
SELECT * FROM tabel2
```

since you have the same columns in all three of them ...

In a general case you should work with column lists like

```
INSERT INTO table3 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tabel1
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tabel2
```

This way you avoid trouble with `auto_increment` id-columns. Also You should consider using `UNION ALL` since `UNION` filters out duplicate lines and therefore will take longer on large tables.