# merge mysql table in one table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've a mysql table named PRODOTTO structured in this way

```
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+
| id | categoria |  prodotto   | quantita | prezzo |
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+
|  1 | bar       | Maxibon     |      887 | 2.00   |
|  2 | bar       | Limonata    |       21 | 1.50   |
|  3 | bar       | Coca Cola   |       70 | 1.50   |
|  4 | bar       | chupa chups |       30 | 0.60   |
|  5 | bar       | pirulo      |       79 | 1.00   |
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+
```

and another one named CONSUMAZIONI

```
+----+----------+----------+--------+-----------------+--------+
| id | prodotto | quantita | prezzo | totale_parziale | status |
+----+----------+----------+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  1 | Maxibon  |        1 | 2.00   | 2.00            | open   |
|  2 | pirulo   |        6 | 1.00   | 6.00            | open   |
+----+----------+----------+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

I'd like to merge this to tables and obtain a unique table like this

```
+----+----------+----------+----------------------+--------+----------------+--------+
| id | prodotto | quantita | quantita_disponibile | prezzo | totale_parziale | status |
+----+----------+----------+----------------------+--------+-----------------+--------+
|  1 | Maxibon  |        1 |                  887 | 2.00   | 2.00            | open   |
|  2 | pirulo   |        6 |                   79 | 1.00   | 6.00            | open   |
+----+----------+----------+----------------------+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

So the new table is the combiantion fo the table CONSUMAZIONI and the column "quantita" of the prodotto's table.
On this new table I will do a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM...
```

Comment: You can make a view ...

Comment: this answer will help you...
[Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597952/mysql-merge-two-tables-into-one-with-union)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Fusione AS 
(SELECT p.id,p.prodotto,c.quantita,p.quantita AS quantita_disponibile,p.prezzo,c.totale_parziale,c.status
 FROM Prodotto P, Consumazione c
 WHERE p.id=c.id
)
```

Also consider to restucture your schema, because you have redundancy in the two tables. Indeed, table Consumazioni should be a relation on table Prodotto. So Consumazioni should be someting like:

id_prodotto | quantità | status

The other information are available by joining the two tables and performing some basic mathematical operations on data (e.g., totale_parziale is prezzo*quatita).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in PHP, or rather in MySQL is Create a VIEW; so you don't always have to make a JOIN.

You can create a view for those tables, like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW prodConsumption AS
    SELECT 
        p.prodotto, c.quantita, p.quantita AS quantita_disponibile, p.prezzo, c.totale_parziale, c.status
    FROM
        PRODOTTO p
    INNER JOIN
        CONSUMAZIONI c ON p.prodotto=c.prodotto
```

Ofcourse, you should look into your table, joining by name is horrible, and your IDs doesn't seem to match.

Afterwards, you can do as you wanted:

```
SELECT * FROM prodConsumption
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `VIEW` for this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_prodotto_consumazinoni AS
    SELECT 
      c.id AS id, 
      c.prodotto AS prodotto, 
      c.quantita AS quantita, 
      p.quantita AS quantita_disponibile, 
      c.prezzo AS prezzo, 
      c.totale_parziale AS totale_parziale, 
      c.status AS `status`
    FROM consumazinoni c INNER JOIN prodotto p ON c.prodotto=p.prodotto;
```

This procudes exactly the output you want:

```
SELECT * FROM view_prodotto_consumazinoni;
id prodotto quantita quantita_disponibile prezzo totale_parziale status
1  Maxibon  1        887                  2      2               open
2  pirulo   6        79                   1      6               open
```

The advantage of such a `VIEW` is that you can define it once and then use it just like an ordinary table without having to think about the `JOIN` done all the time. It is synchronized with the changing data in the two base tables, so always up to date.

I set up a sql fiddler for you, so that you can play around a bit:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76a43/1

Have fun!